# find out friendly page URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

what is the $_SERVER variable that will allow me to see the "friendly" URL treated by htaccess?

For example, `www.example.com/blog/category/keyword` instead of `www.example.com/blog.php?cat=category&kw=keyword` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporary add `print_r($_SERVER)` to your script and check out which values are in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Using just `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will only show: `/blog/category/keyword`.